# Get first values from JSON file in Django/Python

Tags: python, django

I have following JSON file in my python django project:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test (replaced)",
  "code": "test",
  "last_update": "2020-01-01",
  "online": false,
  "data": {
    "temperature": [
      {
        "date": "2019-12-17",
        "value": 23.652905748126333
      },
      ...
    ],
    "humidity": [
      {
        "date": "2019-12-17",
        "value": 23.652905748126333
      },
      ...
```

I need al the data except the values in "data". So I need:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test (replaced)",
  "code": "test",
  "last_update": "2020-01-01",
  "online": false,
  }
```

How can I do this the most efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the JSON file using `json.loads()` and then use the variable as dictionary to access the keys.

Try this, just put proper path to the JSON file :

```
import json
with open('path_to_file/filename.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

id = data["id"]
name = data["name"]
code = data["code"]
last_update = data["last_update"]
online = data["online"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove that key using [`pop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop)

```
json_data.pop('data')
```

or using [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement)

```
del json_data['data']
```

or create another `dict` without modifying original json in dict comprehension

```
final_json_data = {k: v for k, v in json_data.items() if k != 'data'}
```

---

When it comes to efficiency using `del` is the quickest but keep in mind that it modifies your original dictionary (it maters in case you'd want to access `data` in future)

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a={"data": {}, "k": 123}; a.pop("data")', number=10000)
0.007318258999930549
>>> timeit.timeit('a={"data": {}, "k": 123}; del a["data"]', number=10000)
0.004255927000031079
>>> timeit.timeit('a={"data": {}, "k": 123}; b={k:v for k,v in a.items() if k!="data"}', number=10000)
0.007165654999880644
```